# Adding commands in shell scripts to history?

Tags: shell

I notice that the commands I have in my shell scripts never get added to the history list. Understandably, most people wouldn't want it to be, but for someone who does, is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Edit:

Sorry about the extremely late reply.

I have a script that conveniently combines some statements that ultimately result in lynx opening a document. That document is in a dir several directories below the current one.

Now, I usually end up closing lynx to open another document in the current dir and need to keep switching back and forth between the two. I could do this by having another window open, but since I'm mostly on telnet, and the switches aren't too frequent, I don't want to do that.

So, in order to get back to lynx from the other document, I end up having to re-type the lynx command, with the (long) path/filename. In this case, of course, lynx isn't stored in the command history.

This is what I want added to the history, so that I can get back to it easily.

Call it laziness, but hey, if it teaches me a new command....

Cheers.

Comment: Your history contains the commands you have entered, not the contents of those commands. If that's what you want, do you also want the ELF binary code of `bash` in your history? If not, how would you specify which commands to expand inline into your history? Taking one step back, what problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: Why don't you redesign your tool so that your tool prints the path or runs Lynx on it depending on an option?

Answer (score 0):

As @tripleee pointed out, which problem are you actually trying to solve? It's perfectly possible to include [any shell code](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/fcba9aab05af302db134a5dd7fe5a90c7bf9e5b0#.bash_history) in the history, but above some level of complexity it's much better to keep them in separate shell scripts.

If you want to keep multi-line commands in the history as they are, you might want to try out `shopt -s lithist`, but that means searching through history will only return one line at a time.